# Change where the Bootstrap Navbar Container vertical aligns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Trying to figure how to change the default behavior of a container inside the bootstrap navbar. By default it vertically aligns center in the navbar wrapper (see image below), but I want it to be aligned to the top.

[image: Default behiavior]

As of right now I'm using the example Bootstrap provides on their website for the navbar with just a few minor tweaks.

Tried adding a vertical-align property to the .navbar and .container classes but it didn't change anything. Maybe its a flex setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `align-items:center;` on `.navbar` to `align-items: flex-start;`, or you can add the bootstrap utility class `.align-items-start` onto the navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light align-items-start">
    ...
</nav>
```

You can read more about flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/